# Smith Form of a matrix which is already diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Find the Smith form of

$$
\pmatrix{12 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 18 & 0 }$$

I don't find a simple explanation of this algorithm.

Could you please help?
Thank you.

Comment: I think you're going to have to be specific about what you don't understand. You're only likely to get an explanation no clearer than [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form#Algorithm) which is already very clear. People have already tried to be very clear when writing up such things. So it doesn't make sense to ask in the way you have asked.  If you specify, however, you'll have better luck.

Comment: Actually I've already checked the wikipedia page and I think step II is too heavy.  It is suitable for a computer program, but to do the euclid algorithm by hand for each pivot to find bezout coefficients is a tedious task and I think there is a simpler way to do it bu hand?

Comment: OK, well that is definitely more specific. You find the Euclidean algorithm for two small numbers tedious?  Seems pretty easy, especially in this case.

Comment: Here's a start: $\pmatrix{12 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 18 & 0 } \leadsto \pmatrix{12 & 18 & 0 \\0 & 18 & 0 } \leadsto \pmatrix{-6 & 18 & 0 \\-18 & 18 & 0 }$